# $_POST array not populated by form submission

Tags: php, html, post, form-submit

I am working on an email subscribe feature on my website. I encountered an issue where the php is not getting the form values. I have looked at numerous threads on this issue and have not had any luck.

So, how can I get the value of the email field in php?

```
<div>
  <form action="/email.php">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">


    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Email.php

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["email"];
    echo $email;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use / before email.php and you forgot method type

```
<div>
  <form action="email.php" method='POST'>
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">


    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow...i hate php. Turns out my error was "POST" should have been 'POST'

Answer (score 1):

add form method Attribute get or post

```
<form action="/email.php" method = "POST">
```

Comment: This did not do the trick. I get this message in the console: Navigated to url/email.php?firstname=&lastname=&email=test%40email.com

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

**HTML:**

```
<form action="email.php" method='POST'>
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">


    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["save"]))
    {
        print_r($_POST);
        echo $_POST["email"];
    }
?>
```

This will helpful to you.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Every thing written perfectly, just fault's in form tag, remove "/" from action and give method="POST" in form tag.
As you are calling that value with post method in email.php, you have to give the post method on form
like this:-

```
<div>
  <form action="email.php" method="POST">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email">


  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
</div>
```

rest is all fine
now you can call that value:-

```
<?php
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 echo $email;
?>
```